# How to sync files in localhost with phpdesigner 8

Tags: php, wampserver, phpdesigner

I've installed PHPDesigner 8.

I've installed WAMP 2.5.

Both seem to work fine. Note I have already set the PHP path. Going to "Run" in PHPDesigner seems to show the output of a simple HelloWorld.php. Going to `http://localhost` gives the generic WAMP homepage.  Copying HelloWorld.php to C:\wamp\www\HelloWorld.php and then going to `http://localhost/HelloWorld.php` gives the appropriate output. (I then remove the helloworld.php file after that test)

So, with a working WAMP server, my expectation would be that I could do localhost previews using PHPDesigner.  So I click the 'localhost' button in PHPDesigner, expecting that it would run the current php file on the local WAMP server.  Unfortunately, I get an error message that "the path the localhost could not be found".

I remedy that by going to Tools->Preferences then LocalHost and setting the "Local Server Path" to C:\wamp\www\  (the location of the www folder in the WAMP install)  Note it already had the web server address at `http://localhost`.

After that, I try again, repeating the 'localhost' button press. I get a "The file HelloWord.php was not found in the htdocs folder .... The file must be placed in your localhost htdocs folder in order to use the localhost preview" error.

If I do a save-as and save the file to C:\wamp\www then the preview will work (note, it doens't work if I just copy the file there) -- but it's my understanding I could develop in my own area and wouldn't be forced to store all my files in the www folder.  How can I do this?  (basically, how can I have PHPDesigner sync my 'working' folders with the www location when I hit 'localhost' preivew)

As a further bit fun, if I have save-as'd my file into C:/wamp/www/helloworld.php and go to localhost->explorer... then a dialog box named "MViz" with the error "Could not create file mapping object(5)" shows up... followed by another named "MVxfr" with the same error.   Maybe this info points to a solution?

Thanks in advance...

[EDIT:  Yes, I have checked permissions in all areas are open.]

Comment: Sounds like a question for PHPDesigner support

Comment: Agreed, but I'm on day 2 of a trial and the trial version doesn't include support.  If it was something simple, I figured maybe someone would know what setting to change. (PHPDesigner is a bit 'dense')

Comment: Well maybe you should infer something in your trial period about the lack of ease of using this tool and lack of support documentation.